# Promises with recursive calls

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, promise

I am deeply disappointed to not found a solution, to recursively and asynchronously search files in a smb share with promises. My code is probably on the correct way (I hope) but the inner readFiles call, return nothing. Any idea to progress on my difficulties ?

```
readFiles(tree, path).then(files => {
  // all files in dirs
}); 


const readFiles = async (tree: Tree, path: string): Promise<string[]> => {
   const promises:Promise<string>[] = [];
   const entries = await tree.readDirectory(path);

   entries.forEach(entry => {
      promises.push(function(entry) {
         return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {

            const files:string[] = [];

            if (entry.type == "Directory") {
                readFiles(tree, path + "/" + entry.filename.substring(2)).then(items =>
                    items.forEach(item => files.push(item)));

            } else {
                if (entry.filename.toLowerCase().endsWith(".cmz"))
                    files.push(path + '/' + entry.filename.substring(2));
            }

            return resolve(files);
         });
      }(entry));
   });

   return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Comment: You need `return` before the recursive call to `readFiles` otherwise, you don't produce anything from the top-level call.

Comment: VLAZ, could you be more precise ? I added a return but same sounds

Comment: Your `resolve(files)` returns before the readFiles promise comes back in the `then` callback. Why don't you try solving this with async/await instead of creating new promises. You could await the call to `readFiles`.

Comment: A side question: what is `substring(2)` removing from the filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

- You are calling `resolve` synchronously, so `new Promise` will not wait for the recursive promise to resolve first.
- Using `new Promise` is an antipattern when you already have a promise at hand (the one from the recursive call)
- The recursive promise will resolve in an array of file names (if the above is corrected), and `promises` will thus resolve to an array of nested arrays of file names, which you'll want to flatten. So you should call `.flat()` on that resolved array.
- Less problematic, but instead of `.forEach` in combination with `.push()`, use the power of `.map()`, which creates the array for you.

Here is corrected code:

```
const readFiles = async (tree, path) => {
    const entries = await tree.readDirectory(path);
    const promises = entries.map(async entry => {
        let filename = path + '/' + entry.filename.slice(2);
        if (entry.type == "Directory") {
            return readFiles(tree, filename);
        }
        if (filename.toLowerCase().endsWith(".cmz")) {
            return filename;
        }
        return []; // This result will disappear by applying flat().
   });
   return (await Promise.all(promises)).flat();
}
```

Comment: nice solution !